# FILTRO POR URL CON DJANGO VIEWSET

Tags: python, django, api, djangorestframework

Estoy intentando hacer un filtro por url con el parametro "enrollment" pero no me esta funcionando donde puedo estar fallando ?

Aqui la ViewSet:

```
class CarEnrollmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        enrollment = self.request.query_params.get('enrollment')

        return Car.objects.filter(enrollment = enrollment)
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'cars', CarViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path(r'^/(?P<enrollment>.+)/$', CarEnrollmentViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}))
]
```

y aqui el resultado de la consulta 404

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que estas confundiendo un query string con un parametro.

```
path(r'^/(?P<enrollment>.+)/$', CarEnrollmentViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}))
```

En tu `urls.py` tienes enrollment como parte del url. Pero lo tratas de capturar en tu vista como query string con `query_params`.

El url que envias tendría que ser algo asi y quitalo del url si ya no lo necesitas:

http://localhost:8080/tu/path?enrollment=my-enrollment